# How to halve size of sticky navbar so that is only covers half the screen, without resizing navbar img

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am trying to halve the size of my sticky navbar, and have it appear overlayed rather than above of my header image. When I attempt to rescale the container/wrapper divs it seems to adjust the size of the image which I have as the navbar. I also would like to have the dropdown menu appear wherever you are located on the page, rather than just at the top.

I have tried using 'position: absolute' in my css on all of the navbar bits. This seems to work in overlaying the navbar, however it does not appear at the top of the page and the dropdown menu is not accessable.

```css
#wrapper {
     width: 100%;
}
 #demoncontrast {
     filter:contrast(100%) brightness(180%);
}
 .navbar {
     overflow: hidden;
     background-color: #333;
     z-index: 9999;
}
 .navbar a {
     float: left;
     font-size: 16px;
     color: white;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 14px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
}
 .dropdown {
     float: left;
     overflow: hidden;
}
 .dropdown .dropbtn {
     font-size: 16px;
     border: none;
     outline: none;
     color: white;
     padding: 0px;
     background-color: inherit;
     font-family: inherit;
     margin: 0;
}
 .navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
}
 .dropdown-content {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     background-color: #f9f9f9;
     min-width: 657px;
     box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     z-index: 1;
}
 .dropdown-content a {
     float: none;
     color: black;
     padding: 12px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
     display: block;
     text-align: left;
}
 .dropdown-content a:hover {
     background-color: #ddd;
}
 .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
     display: block;
}
 .content {
     padding: 16px;
}
 .sticky {
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     width: 100% 
}
 .sticky + .content {
     padding-top: 102px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="wrapper">
  <div class="navbar" id="myHeader">
   <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">
     <img src="NONENTITYHEADERNB.png" id="opacity" align="left" style="max-width: 50%;height:auto;">
     <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
     <a href="#1">Bio and album stream</a>
     <a href="#2">Where to buy</a>
     <a href="#3">Upcoming shows and links</a>
    </div>
   </div> 
  </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap framework. If Yes mention that version

Comment: I don't quite understand about the part "have it appear overlayed rather than above of my header image". Can you rephrase it please?

Answer (score 0):

> I also would like to have the dropdown menu appear wherever you are located on the page, rather than just at the top.

You have to use the `position` property with `fixed` value: `position: fixed`. This will make your element (in this case is navbar) sticks on window and always moves along with viewers.

And to ensure your element are not overlaid, you may want to add `z-index` property to a certain level. For example: `z-index: 999`.

> When I attempt to rescale the container/wrapper divs it seems to adjust the size of the image which I have as the navbar

The reason lies in here:

```
<img src="NONENTITYHEADERNB.png" id="opacity" style="max-width: 50%;height:auto;">
```

Your `max-width:50%` means this image only allow to have 50% size compare to the parent width, both container and wrapper are its parent.

If I understand you correctly, you want to make the image auto-rescaled when the container change size right? If so, then I afraid you have to put more effort with JavaScript rather then CSS.